# UK Service provider w/ dynamic IP Allocation

Tags: linux, openvz, cloud-hosting, dedicated-server, virtualization

Can anyone recommend an ISP in the UK that allows for dynamic shifting of IP's across servers?

Basically,
I've been working on a test project (as possibly easy to tell from my previous posts) with OpenVZ,
We are ready to go with this project and have successfully been able to get everything up and running,
However we've recently noticed/found out that IP's are only accessible to the host they are assigned to... which obviously isn't going to suffice a service which we wish to deploy whereby if a hardware node fails we migrate all VM's over to a secondary HN.

Could someone recommend a service provider that may/will allow this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to look at a cloud computing/VPS provider which provides a redundant platform, by default if a hardware node fails your machine would fail over to another physical node, and take the IP address with it. In most cases you would only lose 1-2 packets.

As a note, you'll probably find that if you use arping, you can migrate the IP address between machines by informing the border router that the IP address has a new mac address as it's on a new piece of hardware.

> arping -I[device-id] -s[source-ip]
>   [gateway-ip-address]